# Margin-Right on css not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been messing with Coding during school because it interests me the most out of anything at school, and have been self-teaching myself Html-Css-and Js for most of the school year.

I have been re-creating my school's website, and I have run into some problems.

My CSS "Margin-Right" command has not been working.
I have been trying to center a `<Div>` area with CSS and the "Style" command using margin left and right, and the right will never work.
I don't want to just use the `position: absolute;` command because I want some space on the side so you can see the background.
Here is my Html code.

CSS:

```
    .Isaac {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 4px;
      margin-right:100px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="Isaac" Style="Background-color: #E6E6E6 ; Margin-Top: 40px">
      <!-- div content -->
  </div>
```

Edit: The "100x" thing was just a silly error on my part, I meant to have "100px"
Also, I changed Margin-Right: 100x ; to margin-right:100px; and it still have no difference
I hope you can help me

Comment: It would be easier if you copy the relevant codes and paste it here, that way we don`t have to skim through all the code you have in your link. Provide us with the CSS portion that's giving you issues and the HTML as well.

Comment: What is `100x`? Also, try without capitalized initials.

Comment: @IsaacSybrandy - for a start, your commands should look like this: `margin-right:100px;` not `Margin-Right: 100x ;` The big difference here is the `px`.  Take some time and review the CSS section on w3schools.com

Comment: So you've been `self-teaching yourself` ? If so, could I self-teach you not to capitalize any property in CSS ?

Comment: Question edited with irrelevant codes removed. @IsaacSybrandy Impressive work for a 13 year old bro. Keep learning and you might just end up even earning from this as you grow older. And yeah, as mentioned above, avoid capitalising css properties as that is not semantic.

Comment: Some advice about your code:

    Always use different files for HTML/CSS or what else you want to use.
    Always format your code. (Indent,use tabs instead of spaces,align blocks etc) Here is a link to Wiki page Programming Style that might be helpful.

Also when you want to present your code to someone else try using websites like Fiddle or codepen. These little tricks will help, first of all you and then us when we try to help you with your problem

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLyndem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `width:100%` on the `.Isaac` divs. This causes the divs themselves to be as wide as their parent, the body. Then the margins extend to the right of that, off screen.

Solution: remove the `width:100%`.

```css
    
    .Isaac {
      /*width: 100%;*/
      padding: 4px;
      Margin-Right: 100px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .myButton {
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 0px 0px #000000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 0px 0px #000000;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
      background-color: #ffffff;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #000000;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding: 6px 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000000;
    }
    
    .myButton:hover {
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 100%);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .myButton:active {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }

/* I added this, because the body start tag doesn't appear in the snippet */
body {
  background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; Background-size: 100% 100%; background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Mount_Rainier_from_above_Myrtle_Falls_in_August.JPG)
    }
```

```html
  <div class="Isaac" Style="Background-color: #E6E6E6;  Margin-Top: 40px"><img src="http://www.conway.k12.wa.us/sites/default/files/logov4.png" style="width:150px;height:50px;"><a href="#" class="Hello">Menu</a> : <a href="#" class="Hello">Family access</a> : <a href="#" class="Hello"> Facebook/Social Media<a/> : <a href="#" class="Hello"><br><a href="#" class="MyButton">District Office</a>
    <a
    href="#" class="myButton">School Office</a><a href="#" class="myButton">Departments</a><a href="#" class="myButton">Staff</a><a href="#" class="myButton">Family</a><a href="#" class="myButton">Teachers</a><a href="#" class="myButton">Board</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
Margin-Right: 100x;
```

to:

```
margin-right: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

**use text-align center for aligning your contents to center**

- issue with margin-right was you use : x instead of px

  .Isaac {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }

**Hope this is what you want to achieve**
[image]

Comment: I was hoping for the buttons not to be centered, and the background showing on the sides.